# Removing text and imploding comma

Tags: php

Here I have a text block that I'll be inserting into a database but the format is wrong, currently it's presented to me like this :

```
1. 24629583
2. 48676466
3. 73003919
4. 03927166
5. 37734358
6. 37132612
```

When I need it to be like this :

```
24629583,48676466,73003919,03927166,37734358,37132612
```

Is their anyway to do this quickly other than doing `explode()` and then `preg_replace`?

Comment: I wonder what an "imploding comma" looks like...

Comment: One option is `preg_replace("~(\r\n)?\d+\. ~", ',', substr($submitted_string, 3));` - no need to `explode()`.

Comment: You can use two `explode`s and an `array_map`: `implode(",", array_map(function ($item) { return explode(" ", $item)[1];}, explode("\r\n", $text_block)));`.    As a bonus, we get to see an "imploding comma".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$string = '1. 24629583
           2. 48676466
           3. 73003919
           4. 03927166
           5. 37734358
           6. 37132612';

$result = preg_replace('/\s+/', ',', preg_replace('/[0-9]+\.\s/', '', $string));
```

Comment: Have you tried this? I think you're generating a lot of commas!

Comment: This produces the following result : `,,24629583,48676466,73003919,03927166,37734358,37132612,,`

Comment: That was from indentation \s+ should fix it.